# Unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: python

```
def get_month_days ():
    month_days = int(input('Введите дней в месяце  '))
    return month_days

def get_position ():
    get_position = int(input("Укажите должность   1; 2 "))
    if get_position == 1:
        SALARY = 37000
        PIECE_RATE = 822
    else:
        SALARY = 19000
        PIECE_RATE = 653
    return SALARY , PIECE_RATE


    
def get_working_days ():
    working_days = int(input('введи дни рабочие '))
    return working_days

    
def calculate_salary (SALARY, month_days, working_days,):
    salary = SALARY / month_days * working_days
    return salary

def main():
    month_days = get_month_days ()
    working_days = get_working_days ()
    SALARY = get_position ()
    salary = calculate_salary (SALARY, month_days, working_days)
    print (f'Оклад: {salary:.2f}')

main ()
```

во время выполнения функции `calculate_salary()` ошибка.

Comment: get_position возвращает кортеж, может вам нужно его распаковать, а не в одну переменную положить

Comment: только начал изучать код, на практике, может подскажете как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `get_position ()` возращает 'tuple'

```
SALARY = get_position ()
print(type(SALARY))
print(SALARY)

>> <class 'tuple'>
>> (19000, 653)
```

распаковка 'tuple'

```
SALARY, PIECE_RATE = get_position() # SALARY, _ = get_position()
print(type(SALARY))
print(SALARY)

>> <class 'int'>
>> 19000
```

или

```
SALARY = get_position()[0]
print(type(SALARY))
print(SALARY)

>> <class 'int'>
>> 19000
```

[Операторы * и ** в Питоне. Что это и как использовать:](https://kirill-sklyarenko.ru/lenta/zvezdochki-v-python-chto-eto-i-kak-ispolzovat)

```
SALARY = get_position()
print(*SALARY, sep=', ')

>> 19000, 653
```